# Magento2 Product List Widget Cache Problem - prices not reloading

Tags: magento2, frontend, widget, block-cache

I have a product list widget inserted in the content area of a magento 2 store frontpage. The widget is inserted using the following code:

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_count="12" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`19`;]]"}}
```

When switching the site to production mode, product prices are not reloaded when changing currencies. Price reload does work in developer mode and also on the regular category pages. 
Prices are reloaded after refreshing BLOCK_HTML cache in backend but will then cache the currency chosen on first page view. setting the widgets cache TTL to null has no effect.

I also tried adding the widget via layout xml using this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" template="product/widget/content/grid2.phtml" cacheable="false"><!--   -->
        <arguments>
             <argument name="products_count" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
             <argument name="conditions_encoded" xsi:type="string">a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`19`;]]</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I also tried adding `$this->_isScopePrivate = true;` to `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList::__construct()` which is supposed to force Ajax loading, but no success.

Suggestions how to get around this, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: Adding an argument cache_lifetime of xsi:type null did the trick. So if you ever want to add a widget via layout.xml and you want it to be cache-independent, do this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" template="product/widget/content/grid2.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="products_count" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
            <argument name="conditions_encoded" xsi:type="string">a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`19`;]]</argument>
            <argument name="cache_lifetime" xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="null">null</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: And you add that custom layout xml on the cms page/category instead of using a widget instance yeah?

Comment: yes, you can use it on the layout updates section via the backend or any layout xml file you use in your theme or extension

Comment: Note that as of Magento 2.2, it is no longer allowed to set the argument to "null".

Comment: does this even work with FPC ? I pretty sure that this should not work

Comment: I validate your solution and your solution does not work with FPC, so I would say this is not a valid solution, unless you are not using FPC, but please mark it with bold text then

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's a feature that's been added since this question was asked, but there is a "Cache Lifetime (Seconds)" in the parameters when you create the widget as an admin.

If you have multiple currencies, this seems to require setting to 0 as it lasts a day by default.

Seems daft that the widget doesn't contain the code to decide if a day cache or no cache would be the sensible default setting - it would just need to count the currencies being used to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try cache_lifetime="1" in your block, where widget is called.
Something like below,

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" cache_lifetime="1" display_type="all_products" products_count="8" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1.

When I try to insert the "catalog product list" widget on a CMS page it gives me this error.

"Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Magento \ CatalogWidget \ Block \ Product \ ProductsList"

I'm going crazy I don't understand the reason for the mistake.
Thanks for your help